# WinJS window size

Tags: windows-runtime, window, resolution, winjs

I'm building a small WinJS app just for Windows but can't seem to figure out how to set the size of the window at launch. There is obviously some preset size but I can't seem to resize it using CSS or trying to set the window's size directly.

How do you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is due to Microsoft wanting all apps in the Universal app eco-system to use responsive design. I was trying to set an initial screen/window size which doesn't really follow that pattern. If this had been for use on a phone or tablet that would make perfect sense, but the intended target was the desktop so I had hoped to circumvent that design.

I've decided the best course of action is to simply add a div with the correct dimensions and then resize the window (by hand/mouse) to fit around the area of the div since this is just for a personal use project.

Answer (score 3):

You can call this API:

```
var view = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.getForCurrentView();
view.tryResizeView({ height: 500, width: 500 });
Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.preferredLaunchWindowingMode = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewWindowingMode.preferredLaunchViewSize;
Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.preferredLaunchViewSize.height = 500;
Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.preferredLaunchViewSize.width = 500;
```

Comment: No, that didn't change anything. I tried changing the ApplicationView directly before and that didn't help either.

Comment: just to be sure, this is a windows 10 app ?

Comment: It is a Universal Windows Platform app using the template at JavaScript/Windows/Universal. It is WinJS and developed on Windows 10. When I run it, it opens in a small window that you can resize  by dragging the sides and bottoms. Once you resize it and quit and then run it again, the containing window remembers how you last set it. I can get the view.tryEnterFullScreenMode to work and I can get out of full screen mode, I just can't set an actual window size. I now believe it is due to Microsoft wanting all windows in the Universal eco-system to use responsive design.

Comment: Yep, you can't block your window size. The user can still change it. You can try the update response :)

Comment: I don't mind if the user changes it, I am not trying to block them. I just want to set the initial size because this is an app just for me. It is a level builder for a game I am making and I want to ensure the dimensions are what I am using for my game's resolution (before the device resizes it).

Comment: The [ResizeAppView sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/ResizeAppView/js) shows how to do this. You use the `preferredLaunchViewSize` to set the default size for the *next* time your app runs. You use `tryResizeView` to change the size for the *current* view.